# How can I access a socket in VBA?

Tags: sockets, vba

Is it possible to build a micro-webserver using just Excel VBA? I can't find any working examples (some examples found, none working).

Answer (score 0):

If you know .NET programming, you could create an Excel Add-in in VB.NET or C#, add that to Excel. With .NET you can handle all the socket programming, but with the ability to call the methods from Excel VBA. I've personally never done this (never had a reason to), but it is possible.

Hopefully a little help to get started. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=406636.

Also, if you have the appropriate dll's on your system, you should be able to add a reference to the ms winsock library in your vba project. Though I don't know if winsock will work for what you need to do.